# Unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

I am executing the following code:

```
let createByDicc = [
        "nickname" : self.createdBy?.nickname,
        "avatar" : self.createdBy?.avatar,
        "id" : self.createdBy?.id
        ] as! [String : String]

    let dicc = [
        "channelId" : self.channelId!,
        "createBy" : createByDicc,
        "message" : self.message!,
        "type" : "message",
        "replyTo" : "nmartello"
        ] as! [String : String]
```

I am positive that all the variables I am using are not null (self.createdBy?.nickname etc have a string assigned). If I comment out the

```
"createBy" : createByDicc'
```

it works just fine, but if not I get **Unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping an Optional value** . I need this Dictionary inside a Dictionary for the payload of a WS I need to call using Alamofire and I am not sure what it's wrong here. Any ideas?

Comment: also... `dicc` should be `[String:Any]` as you are loading a dictionary in it

Comment: Check the definition of `createByDicc` as it hasn't been assigned a value

Comment: Do all properties of `self.createdBy` (especially `id`) contain a string? Looks like the `createByDicc` can't be casted to `[String: String]` type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: Never (force) cast a dictionary to a specific type. Annotate the type `let dicc : [String : String] = [ ...` then you will get a compiler error which leads you to the issue

Answer (score 1):

First thing, you say that dicc is a [String: String] dictionary, but your createByDicc is not a string, it is another dictionary. so your dicc should be [String: Any].

Second, It is a very good practice to never force unwrap your optionals. Try to either do a `if let` or `guard` statement and save the values or just use Nil Coalescing: `self.message ?? ""`